# Cordova Ionic - changes not taking effect

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

Like the title said. I'm making change in my app (I'm really new in this) but when I refresh the page (after make ionic serve start), the change has not taking effect.

If I change a .html view I can change the effect but, when I change a .json that the app use, not working. Have I need to make a build or something like this?

Comment: @Citizen Android, but I'm trying on chrome

Comment: Looking for this ? `ionic run android -l -c -s`

Comment: Are you editing some third party template ? Because some third party app uses cachefactory to cache the html content. So, if you change content inside templates folder... the output won't get changed.

Answer (score 0):

[Look at the Ionic Docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/test.html) for information on their CLI app.

Is your `json` file inside the watched directories?
If not - the ionic CLI won't be watching it for changes. 
Try explicitly watching your `json` file with your `ionic.project` file, if that still doesn't work - I would suggest taking your question to the [ionic discussion forums](http://forum.ionicframework.com).

Taken from linked website:

By default, LiveReload will watch for changes in your www/ directory, excluding www/lib/. To change this, you can specify a watchPatterns property in the ionic.project file located in your project root to watch (or not watch) for specific changes.

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "app_id": "",
  "watchPatterns": [
    "www/js/*",
    "!www/css/**/*"
  ]
}
```

For a reference on glob pattern syntax, check out globbing patterns on the Grunt website.